# Fixing the width on multiple tables on one line

Tags: html, css, html-table, width

I have multiple tables displayed as inline-block elements. However, I want to fix the widths so that they will out the horizontal space, giving each table a 33% width (3 tables per row). Example code is as follows:

```
<table>
<thead>
<tr><th></th><th></th><th></th><th></th></tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr>
<tr><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr>
<tr><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr>
<tr><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr>
<tr><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

...repeat the above code 2 more times.

Now I can't seem to get it right. All the tables have the class attribute and are set to 33% width, but nothing seems to change.

Answer (score 0):

Other possibility is

```
'float: left'
```

So you don't have to set width to almost 33.3%.
Just make sure you have a **[Clearfix](http://www.webtoolkit.info/css-clearfix.html)** on the table's parent element.

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6x4jP/)**

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
table
{
   float:left;
   width:33%;
}
```

In the percent you have to cater for padding, margin and border issue and reduce it as necessary. You might need to add `display:inline-block` to the container of the 3 tables

Comment: Breaks the page. Sends all the tables on to a line of their own.

Comment: Nope. In any case, I got someone to help me over IRC, and after a bit of fiddling around with div classes, I got it to work. Of course, you fix one thing, you bring up another problem, but I'll save that for another thread. Thanks anyway.